# How to add row specific action buttons in react-bootstrap-table2 (React.js)

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying to add a delete button to every row of my tables rendered with react-bootstrap-table2. I have sorted data by category and placed in my local state

```
state = {
  data: [
    {
      products: [
        {
          name: "Product 1",
          price: "200"
        },
        {
          name: "Product 2",
          price: "300"
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
}
```

and rendered a separate table for each object in `this.state.data` and filled with the data from the products array from the corresponding object using `this.state.data.map((category, index) => ..)`. I have also set the `id` of each of the tables to match the index of the `this.state.data`'s object from where they were rendered from.

But where I struggle is, I want to add a delete button to each row; upon searching, I discovered the `formatter` property for `columns` that provides us `cell, row, rowIndex` but how can I access the table's `id`? So I can potentially use the code in my `columns`:

```
columns = () => {
  ...
  {
    isDummyField: true,
    formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex) => {
      return <Button 
             color="primary"
             onClick={() => {
               console.log (`Product ${rowIndex} of Category ${tableId} deleted`);
             }>
             Delete Product
             </Button>
    }
  }
}
```

I'm lost on how to access `tableId`. Can anyone help me with this? I have always found react-bootstrap-tables very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem from the back-end. Basically I added a unique id to each product and then in the button `onClick=()`, I simply accessed the product's unique id using `row.id`

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution. That's what I needed :))